# "part/page 1 of 2" vs "part/page 1 out of 2"

Tags: difference

What's the difference between "*part 1 of 2*" vs "*part 1 out of 2*"? Are they both correct and synonymous, the latter form being less often used? I am wondering the same when *part* is replaced by *page*.

Comment: From what I've seen, the "out" is only used when the part/page is viewed on its own, as a separate product or item.  When they are kept together, both part and pages would not be listed as "out".

Comment: @Victor that looks like an answer to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've seen, the "out" is only used when the part/page is viewed *on its own*, as a separate product or item.  If (or when) they are kept together (like pages in a document, for instance), both parts and pages would *not* be listed with the "out", but only "**page M of N**" or "**part Y of Z**".